# Using window.open in then callback in Vue/Axios triggers popup blockers in Safari and Firefox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

I'm trying to use window.open to open a PDF for a user in a new tab/window after they complete a registration form that's sent/return via Axios. Is there an easy way to resolve this? I realize that this is just browser behavior since there isn't a click event associated with it. Moving it outside of the Axios request works (I believe the promise breaks the original click event handler), but that defeats the purpose of only firing the window.open on successful registration.

```
validateAndJoin(scope) {
    this.$validator.validateAll(scope).then(result => {
        if (result) {
            var data = {
                ...
            };

            axios.post("/register", data)
            .then(response => {
                ...
                window.open(https://example.com/pdf.pdf , '_blank');
            });
            .catch(e => {
                ...
            });
        }

    });
},
```

Comment: I don't think there's an easy solution to this.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately none of the solutions in the other question worked.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. If you call `window.open()` in the click handler, it should be allowed. Update your question to show how you tried to implement those solutions.

Comment: That’s my very point. I’m not opening it with a click handler—I’m trying to open it as part of the callback. There is an initial click that fires the request, but having the window.open within the callback doesn’t work. Additionally, the accepted answer is that it can’t be done (back in 2014).

Comment: The accepted answer is not the best answer.

Comment: Popup blockers require the window to be opened by a click handler, that's the only way they know how to tell valid popups from malware. So you have to open it with a click handler, then fill it in from the callback.

Comment: Okay. Either way, I’ll try the 2 other solutions and report back if they don’t work again.

Comment: The other two answers are essentially the same, one describes it in words, the other shows code.

Comment: Wonder how this will work on mobile if an empty tab opens... will it navigate the user away from the current tab to a blank one?

Comment: That's a good question, it probably will. But popup blockers are a necessary evil.

Comment: I think the assumption is that the asynchronous operation will be relatively quick, so the user won't notice the blank page before it gets filled in.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I’ll try this later.